Dual Passports: Advice on API and destination entry procedures
Many countries, such as Japan, now require API (Advanced Passenger Information) before travel.
My wife is a dual passport holder (UK passport and Chinese passport with Japanese working permit). We traveled a lot before, but every time she only used her Chinese passport to check in, in order to match the API when returning to Japan, but spent a lot time at the counter for visa checks.
Would using her UK passport to check in allow her to utilize the visa-free entry benefit for British nationals, making the check-in process smoother and allowing for online check-in without needing a visa check?
Upon arrival in Japan, she intends to use her Chinese passport, which is linked to her Japanese working permit. Therefore, Japan immigration may hold a different API record because she checked in with another passport. Would it still OK or would it make things more complicated?

Is the work permit inside the passport or a separate card?

it is a separate card

For API, you should always provide the passport that you will use at passport control in the destination country, for each flight.
Many (most?) airlines allow you to change the passport used whenever you want online, or during check-in (or at the gate if you go there directly), so you can use a different one for each flight. I think I’ve even seen somewhere an airline which allows different inputs for each flight in advance.
So when you depart from Japan and you want to use the UK passport at the destination, so probably anywhere but China:

Booking (if required): UK passport
Check-in: UK passport
Japan exit passport control: Chinese passport with work permit
Gate: UK passport
Destination passport control: UK passport

When flying to Japan:

Booking (if required): CN passport
Check-in: CN passport
Local exit passport control, if there is one: UK passport (or more generally, the one you used to enter)
Gate: CN passport
Japan passport control: CN passport

Sometimes (especially when there’s no exit passport control) the airline will ask for the other passport, just hand it over when they do.
Of course in the case of travel to/from China (which theoretically does not allow dual citizenship) it can be more complex, but as long as you only travel to/from China from/to Japan it shouldn’t be an issue.

"which theoretically does not allow dual citizenship" Every country "theoretically allows dual citizenship". It just depends on the circumstances of how the person acquired the citizenships.

@dda China has limited exceptions for underage children who acquired other nationalities by birth. Keeping them as an adult is a definite no-no though.

Also China isn't the only one. Wikipedia has a really extensive list. Some of them has some sort of equivalend status (see India and OCI) or may allow it on a case by case bases, but have provision that make you lose the citizenship automatically.

Guys i think the question not focus on dual passport travelling to CHINA, so all the trips wont involve chinese immigration at all. regardless that, do you think API still works with different passport?

@sniper2006 My answer is mostly about travel to/from anywhere but China, and tells you what passport you should provide for API purposes (always the passport of the destination country). I and several other users on this site have multiple passports and we routinely use different passports for different flights. Are the instructions in my answer not clear?

@dda Which exactly the point user102008 was making, it makes more sense to focus on the circumstances (in this case: the age) than the notion that some country would “allow” or “disallow” dual citizenship in general.

Also, what does “enforcing Chinese citizenship” mean? If they treat dual citizens as Chinese or prevent them from losing or renouncing their Chinese citizenship, they effectively allow dual citizenship. The only way a country can prevent or limit dual citizenship is by stripping people of their citizenship when they acquire or maintain another one. If they still treat them as citizens after that, they just recognized dual citizenship.

@jcaron thanks, your answer is very clear, but just wondering if you gave different API passport for the destination what ganna happened?

@sniper2006 Different from what? At some point you need to provide a passport that allows you to enter the destination (i.e. either a passport that gives you visa-free/visa-on-arrival entry into the destination country, or a passport and matching visa). If you don't provide that, the airline just won't let you board. If you have two different passports which "can work", then provide whichever one you want. It's usually best if you provide the passport you will actually present to passport control at your destination, but most won't mind (or even know, really).


Would it still OK or would it make things more complicated?

It’s perfectly OK. I hold three passports and routinely mix and match them between check in and immigration. Just this past winter I’ve shown passport A when flying to Mexico but entered it on passport B. Immigration doesn’t really care about APIs, they care about the document you present to them at the counter.
So if it saves you a few minutes for every flight, go ahead and use the UK passport.
Important note: the above does not apply when traveling to/from China. You’ll have to be sure to only use the Chinese passport for those flights as China does not allow dual citizenship. See: I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?

Not going to argue with you, but do wonder - are any of your passports Chinese (which, I would imagine, might add complexity at immigration), or do you work in a country for which you don't hold a passport and, therefore, need a work visa? If not, your experience may be far easier than the OP's wife's.

@FreeMan thanks, updated

thanks for the answer. I still dont get what you mean by They dont care about API? in our case, when you present a chinese passport but the API actually shows on their computer it should be a british passport passenger here, would this cause any problem at the immigration? So what is the point of API ?

@sniper2006 nope doesn’t matter. APIs is mostly for preventing banned travelers from flying to the country as well as some degree of security theater.
